# how to understand this problem in cs61a about scheme macro?

Tags: macros, scheme

I can't understand the Macro example in cs61A,can anyone tells me when the operation evals?

```
scm> (define (twice f) (begin f f))
twice
scm> (twice (print 'woof))
woof
```

I know (print 'woof) first eval to be None and bound to the f,then return (begin None None) is None

but

```
scm> (define (twice f) (begin f f))
twice
scm> (twice '(print 'woof))
(print (quote woof))
```

that makes me  puzzled...

'(print 'woof) first eval to be (print 'woof) and bound to the f,then
in the twice function should return (begin (print 'woof)(print 'woof))
so why not print woof twice?

Answer (score 0):

I will expect that you use Racket. So, documentation for [begin](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._begin%29%29) says:

(begin form ...)

(begin expr ...+)

The second form applies for begin in an expression position. In that case, the exprs are evaluated in order, and the results are ignored for all but the last expr.

In your example, `'(print 'woof)` evaluates to `(print 'woof)`, that's correct. But then, `(begin f f)` is evaluated according to the rules above. `f` is `expr` here, so `f` is evaluated, result is `(print 'woof)`, second `f` is evaluated, result is `(print 'woof)` and finally, only last result is returned and that is `(print 'woof)`.

In other words, your function doesn't return `(begin (print 'woof) (print 'woof))`, but `(begin f f)`.

To get result that you want, `twice` has to be macro.

```
(define-syntax twice
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr) (begin expr expr))))
```

You can check expansion this way:

```
> (syntax->datum
     (expand-to-top-form
      '(twice (print 'woof))))
'(begin (print 'woof) (print 'woof))
```

And you call it like this:

```
> (twice (print 'woof))
'woof'woof
```

Comment: Surely the result is `woofwoof`, not `'woof'woof`? I don't see how a quote would end up in the output. (Okay, after some testing I see it depends what Scheme you use. In Racket, one does indeed get the quotes, but we can see the question uses a different dialect where `print` doesn't quote symbols, based on the last snippet. In that dialect there will be zero quotes.

Comment: In Language settings, Choose Language, Show Details, I have Output Style set to print. If I change it to write, result will be `woofwoof`.